# android - error customizing search suggestion AppCompat theme

Tags: android, search, background, themes, android-appcompat

I'm trying to customize my AppCompat theme (Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) to change search suggestion background color and text.
Here it is my style file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- extend one of the Theme.AppCompat themes -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_blue_200</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_blue_200</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Actionbar Theme -->
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_blue_200</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- SearchView customization-->
        <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
        <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_action_remove</item>
        <item name="searchViewTextField">@drawable/ab_textfield_searchview</item>
        <item name="searchViewAutoCompleteTextView">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/material_blue_200</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

After compilation, I receive this kind of errors:
**Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.

Error:(22, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.

Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.

Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

Hei, Since APPCOMPAT V21, you should change your code to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/your_search_icon</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/your_close_icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This one is the perfect answer. Should have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searchViewTextField, for styling searchView EditText use android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle in Application main style

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>

</style>
<style name="AutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/search_text_color</item>
</style>
```